# pre_save not working in mongoengine update_one

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using Python mongoengine and I would like to define callback, which will be called everytime document is updated.

```
from mongoengine import *
from mongoengine import signals
from time import time

class Item(Document):
    name = StringField()
    modified = LongField()


def update_modified(sender, document):
    document.modified = time()


signals.pre_save.connect(update_modified)
```

However `update_modified` is not called, when I update document:

```
Item.collection.objects(name="First").update_one(name="Second")
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongoengine `.update` does not actually invoke `.save`. It operates directly on db level. And `.update_one` just calls `.update`.
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/51afeca747838614d2545460d83e43ac0c313d4b/mongoengine/queryset/base.py#L621

I am having the same issue here. This is in their guide. Not the best ORM I have used so far not gonna lie... GL
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/96802599045432274481b4ed9fcc4fad4ce5f89b/docs/guide/signals.rst